# Increasing the conditions in IF statement with loop PHP, Diagonal Check

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement, matrix

I have homework to do this program in PHP, that take a matrix and the keywords, so it can find them in the matrix diagonally:

[image]

So this is how the first matrix looks, there are many with different keywords, here for instance keywords are "beef" and "pork". So I made a program for an input that looks like these 2 examples:

[image][image]

There correct input for these two is here:

[image]
[image]

Here is my code that works only in the first case, I don't know how to make a loop that will make more and more conditions instead of writing down all these conditions with && in if statement.

Please give me some tips on how to do it:

```
<?PHP


$input_line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$input_array = explode(" ",$input_line);

// get mojiban
$mojiban = array();
for($ix=0; $ix<$input_array[0];$ix++){
    $mojiban[] = str_split(trim(fgets(STDIN)));
}

//get words
    $words = array();
    for( $kx = 0; $kx < $input_array[1]; $kx++ ){
    $words[] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
}

////check verticales
//get word
    $wordCharArray = array();
for($dx=0; $dx < $input_array[1]; $dx++){
    $wordCharArray = str_split($words[$dx]);

//looping and checking
    
    for ( $line = 0; $line < $input_array[0] ; $line++) {
        for ( $column = 0; $column < $input_array[0] ; $column++ ){
           // for ($wordsNumber = 0; $wordsNumber < $input_array[1] ; $wordsNumber++){
            
                if ($mojiban[$line][$column] == $wordCharArray[0] && $mojiban[$line+1][$column+1] == $wordCharArray[1]) {
                    echo ($column+1)." ".($line+1)."\n";
                
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't understand the expected output. Can you please explain why these numbers should be shown?

Comment: Instead of splitting the input into characters and compare each character with the matrix, you can `implode()` the line or column of the matrix and do a `strpos($line, $word)`

Comment: @El_Vanja for example BEEF starts in 2 column 3 line - > output "2 3", same for PORK 2 column, 1 line -> "2 1"

Comment: @Michel thank you for your answer, but is it possible to do when the keywords are diagonal ?

Comment: So starting point, column-row (I was used to row-column, that confused me). Are these words always going to be in the same direction (top-left to bottom-right)?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes always diagonal from north-west to south-east.

Comment: `@El_Vanja for example BEEF starts in 2 column 3 line` - please edit the question in response to comments - don't leave the question unclear.

Comment: Separate this into individual steps. Write the code/function first, that allows you to check from a starting coordinate x/y, if the given keyword is present in the matrix. That is quite simple - you loop for as long, as keyword has characters, check if the current character is set at the given position, and then you add one to x and y, and proceed with checking the next character. As soon as you find a character that isn’t a match, you know that this keyword does not exist at this position, and you can break the whole thing off. […]

Comment: […] If you can loop to the end, over all characters of the keyword and find a match each time - then the keyword is set at the original x/y coordinate you started with. Then, next, you need to apply this test to all possible starting positions - so that means two nested loops, over x and y coordinates. You should of course make sure, that you don’t go past the maximum array index in each direction. That can either be implemented in your function that checks if a keyword is set at a specific x/y coordinate, […]

Comment: […] or in those two loops over the x/y coordinates - if your keyword is 4 characters long, and your matrix is 6 characters wide - then you only need to perform the check for x=0, x=1 and x=2, because for x>=3, the word won’t fit any more to begin with. (And yes, you should work with zero-based indexes. If you want to present the result by counting rows and columns starting with 1, then add 1 afterwards.)

Comment: @CBroe At the point where your comment has to be split into three parts, you should probably stop and think if it should have been an answer instead, particularly if you're describing how to solve the problem, not how to clarify the question.

Comment: @IMSoP I know, I know … but I still rather want to give OP the chance to develop the solution themselves in a situation like this, rather then present a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution to your problem right now it only checks for diagonal elements. You can refactor as you want from below.

There are many different solutions but the solution for your code I have pasted first checks for the character match in the array. If there is a match, it proceeds to check diagonally for the element from the position that it found the first element.

```
<?php

// First martix
// $searchWords = ["BEEF", "PORK"];
// $matrix = ["HPPLLM", "UROQUV", "FBSRZY", "DPEFKT", "GBBEUY", "EMCQFY"];

// Second martix
$searchWords = ["ABA", "BAB"];
$matrix = ["ACEG", "HBDF", "EGAC", "DFHB"];

// returns true if it diagonally matches the element in matrix from start row
function checkDiagonallyForString(string $search, array $matrix, int $startRow, int $firstMatchPosition)
{
    $endRow = $startRow + (strlen($search) - 2);
    $finding = true;

    foreach (range($startRow, $endRow) as $searchIndex => $rowValue) {
        if (!$finding) {
            break;
        }
        $char = $search[$searchIndex + 1];
        $finding = $matrix[$rowValue][$firstMatchPosition + $searchIndex] == $char;

    }
    return $finding;
}

// format: [word: [column, row]]
$found = [];

foreach ($matrix as $row => $matrixString) {
    if (!count($searchWords)) {
        break;
    }
    foreach ($searchWords as $wordRow => $word) {
        $position = strpos($matrixString, $word[1]);
        if ($position != false) {
            if (checkDiagonallyForString($word, $matrix, $row, $position)) {
                // $position = column of matrix
                // $row = row of matrix
                $found[$word] = [$position, $row];
                unset($searchWords[$wordRow]);
            }
        }
    }

}

// Pretty output
echo "<pre>";
print_r($found);

foreach ($found as $word => $indexes) {
    echo $word . " " . implode(" ", $indexes) . "\n";
}
```

The results are:
[image][image]

**Note: This is a complete answer but before copying and pasting this please try to get a general idea and attempt to solve it yourself. This is not the only way of doing it.**

Answer (score 0):

We can use `implode` tactics from comments. Here is example: [click](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/718d95b5e2e3653754d5dc20a9c822817afb3081).

Code:

```php
// First martix
$searchWords = ["BEEF", "PORK"];
$matrix = ["HPPLLM", "UROQUV", "FBSRZY", "DPEFKT", "GBBEUY", "EMCQFY"];

// Second martix
// $searchWords = ["ABA", "BAB"];
// $matrix = ["ACEG", "HBDF", "EGAC", "DFHB"];

$matrixStr = implode('', $matrix);
$matrixSize = count($matrix);
$positions = [];

foreach ($searchWords as $wordIdx => $word) {
    $wordSize = strlen($word);
    $found = false;
    for ($y = 0; $y <= $matrixSize - $wordSize && !$found; $y++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $matrixSize - $wordSize && !$found; $x++) {
            $allLettersOk = true;
            for ($l = 0; $l < $wordSize; $l++) {
                if ($matrixStr[$y * $matrixSize + $x + $l * $matrixSize + $l] != $word[$l]) {
                    $allLettersOk = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($allLettersOk) {
                $positions[$word] = [$x + 1, $y + 1];
                $found = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($positions as $word => $indexes) {
    echo $word . " " . implode(" ", $indexes) . "\n";
}
```

If you need a description to this code - write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
// First martix
$searchWords = ["BEEF", "PORK"];
$matrix = ["HPPLLM", "UROQUV", "FBSRZY", "DPEFKT", "GBBEUY", "EMCQFY"];

// Second martix
// $searchWords = ["ABA", "BAB"];
// $matrix = ["ACEG", "HBDF", "EGAC", "DFHB"];

$matrixStr = implode('', $matrix);
$matrixSize = count($matrix);
$positions = [];

foreach ($searchWords as $wordIdx => $word) {
    $wordSize = strlen($word);
    $found = false;
    for ($y = 0; $y <= $matrixSize - $wordSize && !$found; $y++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $matrixSize - $wordSize && !$found; $x++) {
            $allLettersOk = true;
            for ($l = 0; $l < $wordSize; $l++) {
                if ($matrixStr[$y * $matrixSize + $x + $l * $matrixSize + $l] != $word[$l]) {
                    $allLettersOk = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($allLettersOk) {
                $positions[$word] = [$x + 1, $y + 1];
                $found = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($positions as $word => $indexes) {
    echo $word . " " . implode(" ", $indexes) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$input_array` contains your matrix, at each position you have a character, like this

```
$input_array = [
    ['H', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'L', 'M'],
    ['U', 'R', 'O', 'Q', 'U', 'V'],
    ['F', 'B', 'S', 'R', 'Z', 'Y'],
    ['D', 'P', 'E', 'F', 'K', 'T'],
    ['G', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'U', 'Y'],
    ['E', 'M', 'C', 'Q', 'F', 'Y'],
];
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that you also have an array of arrays. I know you have strings, but string operations would make this solution difficult to read and we are mostly interested in the algorithm, so, for the sake of understandability I will not start from your actual data structure, but will answer questions if you have difficulty implementing this into your solution:

```
$words = [
    ['B', 'E', 'E', 'F'],
    ['P', 'O', 'R', 'K']
];
```

Notice that beef and pork are of the same length, but let's not assume that all words are of the same length.

```
//Computing row count so it can be reused
$rowCount = count($input_array);
//Computing the column count so it can be reused
//We assume that each row of the matrix has the same number of columns
$colCount = count($input_array[0]);
//Looping the rows
for ($row = 0; $row < $rowCount; $row++) {
    //Looping the columns of the row
    for ($column = 0; $column < $colCount; $column++) {
        //Computing the max length of allowed words
        $maxLength = min($rowCount - $row, $colCount - $col);
        //Looping the words
        for ($wIndex = 0; $wIndex < count($words); $wIndex++) {
            //Storing the length of the current word for later use
            $charCount = count($words[$wIndex]);
            //We avoid checking for the presence of words that are
            //Longer than the current position allows
            if ($charCount <= $maxLength) {
                //match is initialilzed with true and will be set false at
                //the first mismatch. If no mistmatch is found, then we know
                //that the word is present at the current position
                $match = true;
                //Looping the word's characters and check for possible
                //mismatches
                //Notice that we stop the loop either at the first mismatch
                //or at the last character if there is no mismatch
                for ($cIndex = 0; $match && ($cIndex < $charCount); $cIndex++) {
                    //If the word character at cIndex offset mismatches
                    //the character of input array at the same offset, starting
                    //from the [$row][$column] position, then it mismatches
                    if ($words[$wIndex][$cIndex] !== $input_array[$row + $cIndex][$column + $cIndex]) $match = false;
                }
                if ($match) {
                    //Say the word
                    echo implode("", $words[$wIndex]) . " found at row " . ($row + 1) . ", column " . ($column + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```